# Not sure if this idea for calculating the square roots of a value has any merit

Tags: trigonometry

Okay, so I was thinking about square roots the other day and I spent some time thinking of how to visualize them:

Say we have 10,000.

The square root would be 100. So 100 of 100 equals 10,000.

Now what if you had a 100 sided polygon with each side segment being equal to 100? Wouldn't there be a strong correlation between the squared value of the side length and the approximated circumference of the circle that best fits this polygon?

I don't know too much about trig identities but it seems to me you should be able to make a good guess for the square root of a number (it would be more accurate the higher the number) by relating it to the approximated circumference?

**This is mostly for making the initial guess when finding a square root with software by the way**

I can't figure out how to evaluate for S in the following equation (where X is already solved by the program, which I have figured out so far)

X = s/sin(180/s)

Comment: This doesn't help since the radius of the circle is not rational.

Comment: Typically you go about this the other way around, using the polygons to approximate the circle. This is because you need the value of $\pi$ to do it the other way around and $\pi$ is even less well-behaved than square roots.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your method, or the point of it. Speed? Accuracy?

Several methods for approximating square roots are described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots).

Curious to know why you don’t just call the sqrt function provided by whatever programming language you’re using. The guys who implemented it know far more about square root approximations than you or I do.

Comment: I just feel like for really large values the relationship to the circumradius could prove useful for making an initial guess when calculating square roots, but I don't know how to evaluate some of the functions. The biggest problem I have is:

Comment: X is already defined by the program and we know the value, but I am unsure how to solve for S

Comment: x = s/sin(180/s)

Comment: If I can get the equation in the form: S = " " then it should provide a very quick initial guess for the square root

Comment: Basically I am taking an input value we want to find the square root of, treating that input like the perimeter of a polygon with s sides each of length s

Comment: The perimeter will be very close to the circumference of the polygons circumradius

Comment: And using the formula:

Comment: radius = s / 2 sin (180/n) where s is the number of sides and n is length of the side, just working backwards

Comment: Seems to me that you’re replacing the nice simple equation $s^2 = x$ by a more complex equation that will be harder (and slower) to solve.

Comment: I planned on comparing their calculation times but I can't do that if I can't solve this trig identity

Comment: @JackHulse It seems clear the method you have in mind is overcomplicated. Even a binary search using guess-and-test is very fast for finding square roots compared to any trigonometric methods would be because you'd have calculate the trig functions.